# Are there any issues with buying a used Siddur?

Tags: halacha, transactions, prayer-book

I have found two Siddurim online that I would like to purchase. However, they are used. I am wondering if there is any issues with this.

Comment: Not at all, enjoy.

Comment: It'sa mitzvah to restore a worn Siddur, and perhaps, even obligatory, assuming that it can be repaired. As a matter of fact, I've often found that "old", esp. European Siddurim are sometimes more "accurate" (e.g. - the Yiddish or Hebrew instructions) than the "modern" English instructions found in some of today's Siddurim. Not a majority, mind you, but many, IMO. Most important thing to seek after accuracy and quality (binding, paper quality, font style, perhaps,) is your own "comfort". Some prayers are placed differently in different Siddurim, e.g. so that may be a factor for you, as well.

Answer (score 6):

I've never heard of any issue with it, and [Rabbi *Kasriel* Kaplan](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5766/BMD66arkaplan.htm) [has bought used *sidurim*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=27836&pgnum=20). So it seems to be fine to do so.